# CSS3 animate one after another with delay

Tags: css, css-transitions

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4HKwV/) -

I've got some `divs` that has some css3 transition. Is it possible to apply this transition not for every item at once but for example with `100ms delay` after each another item?

```
#main div {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s opacity;
}

#main.active div{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

So when I'll add `.active` class to `#main`, its children will change its opacity not at once, but one after another?

I know it can be easly done with

`$('.setOfItems').each(function(i){ $(this).delay(100*i).doSth() })`

But I'm looking for just css3 solution.

Comment: Something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/4HKwV/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `transition-delay` property.
read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) , [or here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp)

Check out this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4HKwV/4/)

by setting a differnet delay to different elements they will appear at different times.
but the CSS is going to look messy if you'll set a bunch of different classes with different delays, so you should apply the delay from a Script (simmilar to what you suggested in your question).

if you have a small and constant number of elements, you can do it the ugly way (again: the best way is via script)

```
#main div:first-child
{
    transition: 1s opacity 200ms; /*BTW this is the short way of using transition with the duration, property, delay*/
}

#main div:nth-child(2)
{
    transition: 1s opacity 400ms;
}

#main div:nth-child(3)
{
    transition: 1s opacity 600ms;
}

etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way but it's not fully supported, please take a look on [keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

Then you will need to create each element different class.