# CSS transition: go to one value and then to another

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to create an animation with two steps: first the css property goes to value A and when it's done, go to value B. Is this possible with css transition alone without jQuery?

I would like to achieve something like this with pure CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/t2w2btow/1/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".red" ).animate({
    left: "100"
  }, 1000, function() {
      $( ".red" ).animate({
        left: "400"
      }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763701/css3-animate-one-after-another-with-delay

Comment: @Alendorff How can it apply on the same property? From what I understand there can be one transition delay per property

Comment: take a look at keyframes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@keyframes moveLeft {
   0% {left: 0;}
   50% {left: 100px;}
   100% {left 400px;}
}

.red {
   animation: moveLeft 2s forwards;
}
```

When the red class is added to the element, the **moveLeft** animation should trigger.  You can test by using `.red:hover` instead and hovering the element.  You might need the browser prefixes for the [animation & keyframes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You have the steps() option with transition if this is what you meant :
example with 2 steps :

```css
.red {
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition:left 1s steps(2,end);
}
body:hover .red{
    left:400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
```

if you want it to remain where it ended :

```css
.red {
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
   transition:left 100000s 0s;/* very long delay freezes it */
    
}
body:hover .red{
    left:400px;
  transition:left 1s steps(2,end);
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
```